# В строковой переменной задать условие для if

Tags: python, python-3.x

В строковой переменной задать условие для if. Мне была предоставлена БД в таблице которой есть поле фильтр следующего вида "a=="0100" or a=="1050" or ..." Значение в каждой строке поля меняется в том числе и по числу параметров. Теперь к сути мне хотелось бы реализовать следующую конструкцию.

```
filtr=Извлекаемое условие фильтрации из БД (a=="0100" or a=="1050" or ...)

if filtr:
....
else:
....
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать.

Comment: операторы условия только `or` или есть и другие?

Comment: Параметр "a" - это именно переменная в коде с таким названием, или это ключ из какой-то коллекции/хранилища ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял то такой код должен работать:

```py
filtr=Извлекаемое условие фильтрации из БД (a=="0100" or a=="1050" or ...)

if eval(filtr):
....
else:
....
```

PS: Функция `eval` выполняет простой python-код.

Answer (score 0):

C учетом того, что **eval — зло**, и возможно, не всегда его стоит использовать, предлагаю вариант на регулярках в случае, когда условие однотипно, иначе, при наличии других операторов в условии этот код придется слегка усложнить:

```
import re

db_filter = '(a=="0100" or a=="1050")'

if a in re.findall(r'\d+', db_filter):
  ...
else:
  ...
```